# Pixate ios UITextField border won't show

Tags: ios, objective-c, css

broder property won't show border for uitextfield
this is my code

```
.txtField{
left :300px;
top :300px;
width :100px;
height :100px;
border-radius: 5;
-ios-border-style: none;
background-color: #ffffff;
border-width: 10px;
border-color: black;
}
```

Comment: you want the result ?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set a border-style property :)

**CSS**

```
border-style:solid;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8ejqrg1h/

Comment: okay it's correct on jsfuddle but on ios it doesn't show any border and i don't know why :(

Comment: Change the background-color of your txtField, and tell me if that's changed the color of your element :)

Comment: You're welcome bro' :), can you accept the answer pls ? :3

Comment: It's ok, have a nice day :)